# WP8 back button go two steps back

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to figure out how I could go two pages back in windows phone 8 sdk.
I know I can overwrite the function:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
```

the problem is, that I can not understand how I could go two pages back...
I have an app that is like that:

Display Overview > select Booking > Confirm Booking > Booking done

When bookking is done I would like to go back to the Overview page...

Anyone some suggestions?

Comment: Hi can You plz Tell Me How you Solve This Problem . I read The article But I'm confused . so plz share any sample code .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [**this article**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394012%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). It describes in detail how to use the `BackStack` property and the `RemoveBackEntry` method to manipulate the navigation history. You'll want to update the Back Stack, by removing the last entry. Removing the last entry will allow you to navigate back two pages.

You could use something like this:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    RootFrame.RemoveBackEntry();
    base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! in fact I saw this article before, but was not 100% sure.. now I have read more careful and everything works!

Comment: @Ihan16 Plz Share any sample code for this question. i'm unable to find solution form the article

Comment: Code sample is in my answer.. That is literally the only code you need, just put it in your page. If you're debugging, put a break point on `RootFrame.RemoveBackEntry()` and after you navigate to the page which has the code, hit the Back button in the emulator or the phone and the breakpoint should be hit.

Comment: Can You Plz Come On Chat

Comment: check out this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394012(v=vs.105).aspx