# How to resolve back button issue in windows phone 8 game application?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

This question may be  possible duplicate of 
[WP8 back button go two steps back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524500/wp8-back-button-go-two-steps-back)

My game page structure as follow

**MainPage**(Select New Game) - > **Level1** Page(After complete 60 sec this page automatically goto next page->**Alert page** (it contain TryAgain-Home-Exit Buttons if user click TryAgain Button "*Level1*" Page Show)

My problem start here..

Now User in "*Level1*" user click phone back button it show the **Alert Page** . it's wrong

but correct way is from "*Level1*" to **MainPage**

I try following code in **Level1** Page

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        RootFrame.RemoveBackEntry();
        base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
    }
```

I got error in RootFrame *The name 'RootFrame' does not exist in the current context*

Any one tell me where i made mistake and what code i need to add for RootFrame. this is my first Wp8 game app development. Thank You

Comment: after you receive an answer from your alert page you need to remove it from the stack. See this MS article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394012(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem. The tutorial uses `RootFrame.RemoveBackEntry();`
The default is `NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();`